# How to use variable value as variable name | C#

Tags: c#, variables

I want to name variables in a for loop with the current value of 'i'.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= groupAmount; i++) {

    int [value of i] = someNumber;

}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that how would you use it later? You can create a dictionary and put in a value using the value of `i` as a key.

Comment: Either (1) use **Reflection** to get the member/property, or (2) use a **Dictionary** to associate each integer with a value.  Can you give an example of the values you are trying to access?  Show us how they are declared...and **where** they are declared.

Comment: Any time you want to have a bunch of variable names which are just incrementing numbers, what you're looking for is generally an *array*.  (Or a List, or a Dictionary, or some collection type in the language of choice.)

Comment: this is almost never the desired way. This is likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282). You must describe your real problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you not to use this approach, for that they exist types that allow to store information, for my part I propose you this simple solution in the same time effective .

```
Dictionary<int, int> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<int, int>();
for (int i = 0; i <= groupAmount; i++)
{
     keyValuePairs[i] = someNumber;
}
```